# java BigInteger random number in a minimum and maximum range

Tags: java, random, biginteger

In java, it's easy to find random number using Random() in a range.

Below is a method I've tried to do that.

```
public int rand(int min, int max){
    Random rands = new Random();
    int numRand = rands.nextInt(max-min) + min;
    return numRand;
}
```

But, it's in integer which has 2,147,483,647 as maximum values.

Then, I need to compute some values that has large number.

Let's say the large number is `5234960860151076037807790832396537967963815240976924943830782457906435372625549206966897650382309539933354611312768681026528740101`

It contains 130 characters of number. It can't be stored in integer, even in double. But, I need to find large random number like that.

So, I found the way to random large number with using BigInteger.

At [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709521/how-do-i-generate-a-random-n-digit-integer-in-java-using-the-biginteger-class), the random number just for n-digit.

At [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java), the random number from 0 to n. It's similar with [this](http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/creating-a-random-biginteger-in-java.html).

At [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735664/randomizing-a-biginteger), the random number from 1 to `8180385048`.

So far, I found them useful. But I'm still confusing how to know whether the minimum number is `0` or `1` or `123456712312`.

I want to generate random number using BigInteger from minimum to maximum values, such as from `123456712312` to `12345678910213212312312312312312`.

So, how can I find random number from that range (from `123456712312` to `12345678910213212312312312312312`)?

Comment: Use SecureRandom.nextBytes.  (You'll probably have to figure out the range thing yourself, though.)

Comment: 1- find the number of digits using an ordinary random generator 2- inside a for loop create a one digit random integer and add it to a string holding the hole random number (you may need to check some conditions to stay in bound)

Comment: Consider: If your random numbers are evenly distributed between 123456712312 and 12345678910213212312312312312312 then only one value in 2**20 will be only 12 digits long.  So you'd have to sample about one nonillian times (yes, that's a real word) to get a number that small.